# be surprised that someone should/should have done something

Tags: subjunctives

> 1 I am surprised that he should say that yesterday.
>
> 2 I am surprised that he should have said that yesterday.

I think that they mean almost the same but they are not identical. What's the difference?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in meaning.

Comment: We're [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surprised+that+he+should+say%2Csurprised+that+he+would+say&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) to be *...surprised that he **would** say that* today. But note that ***yesterday*** in your example *can't* affect the syntax, because the speaker can *only* be surprised if he really *did* say it (in the ***past***). If him saying that *wasn't* a definite known thing that really happened *in the past*, it would be expressed as *I **would be** surprised **if he said that*** (yesterday OR tomorrow).

Answer (score 1):

**should** is a reported speech marker there, "is alleged to have said". (Compare German **sollen** in newspapers and TV news when the news person is speaking of something alleged to have been done or said by somebody.) The speaker is not conceding that he actually said such a thing.

> I am surprised that he should say such a thing.

Paraphrase: I think he would never say such a thing. I am surprised to hear (from someone) that he did. Or I am having trouble "believing my own ears".

> I am surprised that he should *have said* such a thing.

Paraphrase: I think would not have said such a thing. I am surprised to hear that he did, or ditto (... own ears).

> *I am surprised that he should say such a thing yesterday.

I'm marking that one as unidiomatic because of *yesterday*. Paraphrase (unidiomatic): I think he would never say such a thing yesterday.

> I am surprised that he should have said such a thing yesterday.

Paraphrase: I think he would not have said such a thing yesterday and I am surprised to hear that he did, or ditto (... own ears).

> I am surprised that he should have said such a thing yesterday, of all days.

I think he would not have said such a thing yesterday, of all days, and  I am suprised to hear that he did, or ditto (... own ears).

Answer (score -3):

*He should say* is present (or future) tense:

> I’ll be ready with the hose in case a fire **should** break out

*He should have said* is past tense:

> With his grandmother now dead, he would never learn why she **should have done** it that way.

Comment: You have completely mangled and distorted my examples up to the point that your answer answers a question which I didn't ask. My first sentence legitimately refers to the past while your first sentence makes a reference towards a future action. They are incomparable. Plus you completely disregarded the presence of "I am surprised" which brings the subjunctive at play.

Comment: Well that’s quite a warm reception. What do you reply to those who **intended** to ruin your day?